# Questions about ddrescue reverse option

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ddrescue

In ddrescue you can add option -R (reverse) to read backwards from the source.

Will this affect the recovery speed?

If you have a log file (mapfile), you can then easily switch between forward and backward, with and without -R without problem/not hurt the target?

When I started using ddrescue I had a problem with it stopt trying at 20%. I then started backwards with -R. When I used forward, my * .img file kept growing. When I started running backwards, my *.img file is always as big as my source (the hard drive I am saving). Is this correct? I can see that saved data is growing in ddrescue even if my img file is full size.

My speed with the -R option is about 100-200KB/s (very slow) any my time now is about 95 days. Can I speed this up or is it only because my drive is bad?

I use this in Ubuntu from a USB.

```
sudo ddrescue -d -n -R /dev/sdg1 /media/ubuntu/lagring/deive.img /media/ubuntu/lagring/deive.log
```

Comment: Its because your drive is bad. Ive not found reading in reverse noticeably slower then reading forward (on HDD). Its worth noting that the inside tracks of an HDD are at the end of the drive and generally about half the speed of the outside tracks.

Answer (score 0):

Going forward, data is written as rescued and the file grows accordingly.
Going backward means that the target file must be allocated with the same
size as the source in order to have somewhere to write the saved sectors.

`ddrescue` has some options that can speed up at least the first pas, but this
is done manually on a trial and error basis.

The option `-n` (no-split) together with `-r 1` (retry once) and setting `-c`
(cluster size) to a smaller value may help.

The option `-a, --min-read-rate=<bytes>` specifies the minimum read rate of
good areas in bytes/s.
Specifying a size like `10M` may skip first areas that are still readable
but extremely slowly, continuing with areas that can still be read quick enough.

You could also run in `--reverse` mode to read the disk back-to-front,
or force it to start at a specific offset with `--input-position=X` to skip
into a faster region.

The options of `--no-scrape` or `--no-trim` might be able to speed up the recovery
of the easy parts by entirely omitting trying the damaged sectors.
You could also try values for the `--skip-size` option to see if larger or smaller
values than the default will speed things up.