# Interpreting failing SSD S.M.A.R.T. report. Windows stuck in boot-loop

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, smart

I received laptop (DELL Latitude E7450) with failing SSD.
Windows stuck in boot-loop, with no standard repair/rescue tools working.

What I had done to this moment:

1. I confirmed boot-loop.
2. Bios recognizes SSD.
3. Pre-boot diagnostics returned only SSD error:

Error Code: 2000-0142

4. List item

Fortunately disk is readable and can be mounted in Linux (Lubuntu 20.10) booted from pendrive.

- I've copied most important files to pendrive (using Lubuntu file manager).
- I've checked SSD with gsmartcontrol. There are errors in short self test and extended self test. SMART attributes are unclear for me, so **I would like to ask for your help in understanding health of the drive, source of possible problems and if it could be fixed or should I recommend buying a new drive.**

Also, could you point out best command to copy all undamaged data from SSD to another drive?
I'm pretty sure I have all important files, but I always prefer to copy whole drive just to be safe.
I don't want to overstress damaged(?) SSD to the point of unrecoverable failure.

Bellow you'll have full gsmartcontrol report:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.8.0-25-generic] (local build)

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SK hynix SATA SSDs
Device Model:     SK hynix SC300 mSATA 512GB
Serial Number:    FJ56N651311006P18
Firmware Version: 20001P00
User Capacity:    512,110,190,592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      mSATA
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Mar 15 11:45:11 2021 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     254 (maximum performance)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x06) Offline data collection activity
                    was aborted by the device with a fatal error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 118) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    2) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x19) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  60) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 0
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   166   166   006    -    0
  5 Retired_Block_Count     -O--CK   253   253   036    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   093   093   000    -    6586
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   020    -    3806
100 Total_Erase_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    10782675
171 Program_Fail_Count      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1
172 Erase_Fail_Count        -O--CK   253   253   000    -    0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  ----CK   100   100   000    -    260
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1
176 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot -O--CK   253   253   000    -    0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     -O--CK   098   098   000    -    76
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    49
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   -O--CK   100   100   000    -    511
180 Erase_Fail_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    8321
181 Non4k_Aligned_Access    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  -O--CK   253   253   000    -    0
183 SATA_Downshift_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    2
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    2336
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   253   253   000    -    0
191 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   -O--CK   253   253   000    -    0
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O----   030   000   000    -    30 (0 254 0 127 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    20375846
201 Percent_Lifetime_Remain -OSR--   100   100   000    -    0
204 Soft_ECC_Correction     -OSR--   100   100   000    -    1
231 SSD_Life_Left           PO--CK   253   253   010    -    0
234 Unknown_SK_hynix_Attrib -O--CK   100   100   000    -    38951
241 Total_Writes_GiB        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    13632
242 Total_Reads_GiB         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    22696
250 Read_Retry_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    190010
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      4  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      5  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      2  Extended self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x30       GPL     R/O      2  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (5 sectors)
Device Error Count: 65535 (device log contains only the most recent 20 errors)
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 65535 [7] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 00 d8 00 00 00 73 dd 60 40 40     00:33:19.940  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 d0 00 00 00 73 dc 60 40 40     00:33:19.940  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 c8 00 00 00 73 db 60 40 40     00:33:19.940  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 c0 00 00 00 73 da 60 40 40     00:33:19.940  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 b8 00 00 00 73 d9 5f 40 40     00:33:19.940  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65534 [6] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 00 30 00 00 00 73 d9 60 40 40     00:33:19.880  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 28 00 00 00 73 d8 60 40 40     00:33:19.880  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 20 00 00 00 73 d7 5f 40 40     00:33:19.880  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 18 00 00 00 73 d7 5e 40 40     00:33:19.880  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 10 00 00 00 73 d7 5d 40 40     00:33:19.880  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65533 [5] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 00 c0 00 00 00 73 d6 60 40 40     00:33:19.810  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 b8 00 00 00 73 d5 60 40 40     00:33:19.810  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 b0 00 00 00 73 d4 60 40 40     00:33:19.810  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 a8 00 00 00 73 d3 60 40 40     00:33:19.800  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 a0 00 00 00 73 d2 60 40 40     00:33:19.800  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65532 [4] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 98 00 00 01 20 41 a0 40 40     00:33:19.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 90 00 00 00 73 cc 60 40 40     00:33:19.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 88 00 00 00 73 cb 60 40 40     00:33:19.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 80 00 00 00 73 ca 60 40 40     00:33:19.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 78 00 00 00 73 c9 60 40 40     00:33:19.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65531 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 00 b8 00 00 00 73 b9 60 40 40     00:33:19.660  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 b0 00 00 00 73 b8 e0 40 40     00:33:19.660  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 20 00 a8 00 00 00 71 b8 e8 40 40     00:33:19.660  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 a0 00 00 00 71 b8 e0 40 40     00:33:19.660  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 98 00 00 01 74 12 58 40 40     00:33:19.660  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65530 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 00 28 00 00 00 73 dc 60 40 40     00:01:26.040  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 20 00 00 00 73 db 60 40 40     00:01:26.040  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 18 00 00 00 73 da 60 40 40     00:01:26.040  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 10 00 00 00 73 d9 5f 40 40     00:01:26.040  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 73 d9 5e 40 40     00:01:26.040  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65529 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 73 d8 60 40 40     00:01:25.970  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 f8 00 00 00 73 d7 5f 40 40     00:01:25.970  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 b8 00 00 00 73 d7 5e 40 40     00:01:25.970  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 b0 00 00 00 73 d7 5d 40 40     00:01:25.970  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 01 00 a8 00 00 00 73 d7 5c 40 40     00:01:25.970  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65528 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 00 78 00 00 00 73 d6 60 40 40     00:01:25.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 70 00 00 00 73 d5 60 40 40     00:01:25.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 68 00 00 00 73 d4 60 40 40     00:01:25.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 60 00 00 00 73 d3 60 40 40     00:01:25.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 58 00 00 00 73 d2 60 40 40     00:01:25.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65527 [19] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 98 00 00 01 20 41 a0 40 40     00:01:25.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 90 00 00 00 73 cc 60 40 40     00:01:25.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 88 00 00 00 73 cb 60 40 40     00:01:25.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 80 00 00 00 73 ca 60 40 40     00:01:25.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 01 00 00 78 00 00 00 73 c9 60 40 40     00:01:25.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65526 [18] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 01 00 00 40 00 00 00 73 b9 60 40 40     00:01:25.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 38 00 00 00 73 b8 e0 40 40     00:01:25.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 20 00 30 00 00 00 71 b8 e8 40 40     00:01:25.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 28 00 00 00 71 b8 e0 40 40     00:01:25.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 20 00 00 01 74 12 58 40 40     00:01:25.740  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65525 [17] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  00 -- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.750  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.720  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.720  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.670  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  f5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.600  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK

Error 65524 [16] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6585 hours (274 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  00 -- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.750  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.720  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.720  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.670  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  f5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:19.600  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK

Error 65523 [15] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6583 hours (274 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 f8 00 00 02 4c 8c f0 40 40     09:28:50.970  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 a0     09:28:50.970  READ LOG EXT
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     09:28:50.970  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 e0     09:28:50.970  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     09:28:50.970  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 65522 [14] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6583 hours (274 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 d0 00 00 02 4c 8c f0 40 40     09:28:50.920  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 c8 00 00 02 4c 8d b0 40 40     09:28:50.920  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 c0 00 00 02 4c 8d a8 40 40     09:28:50.920  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 b8 00 00 02 4c 8d a0 40 40     09:28:50.920  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 b0 00 00 02 4c 8d 98 40 40     09:28:50.920  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65521 [13] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6583 hours (274 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 70 00 00 02 4c 8c f0 40 40     09:28:50.870  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 a0     09:28:50.870  READ LOG EXT
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     09:28:50.870  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 e0     09:28:50.870  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     09:28:50.870  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 65520 [12] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6583 hours (274 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 70 00 00 02 4c 8c f0 40 40     09:28:50.830  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 a0     09:28:50.830  READ LOG EXT
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     09:28:50.830  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 e0     09:28:50.830  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     09:28:50.830  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 65519 [11] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6583 hours (274 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 60 00 00 02 4c 8c f0 40 40     09:28:50.780  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 58 00 00 02 4c 8c e8 40 40     09:28:50.780  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 50 00 00 02 4c 8c e0 40 40     09:28:50.780  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 48 00 00 02 4c 8c d8 40 40     09:28:50.780  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 40 00 00 02 4c 8c d0 40 40     09:28:50.780  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65518 [10] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6582 hours (274 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 08 00 00 02 33 10 28 40 40     08:43:42.150  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 a0     08:43:42.140  READ LOG EXT
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     08:43:42.140  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 e0     08:43:42.140  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     08:43:42.140  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 65517 [9] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6582 hours (274 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 00 00 00 02 33 10 28 40 40     08:43:42.100  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 a0     08:43:42.100  READ LOG EXT
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     08:43:42.100  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 e0     08:43:42.100  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     08:43:42.100  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 65516 [8] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 6582 hours (274 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 70 00 00 02 33 10 28 40 40     08:43:42.050  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 a0     08:43:42.050  READ LOG EXT
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     08:43:42.050  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 e0     08:43:42.050  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 a0     08:43:42.050  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (2 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       60%      6585         1309200
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      6585         1309064
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       60%      6585         1309200
# 4  Short offline       Completed: read failure       60%      6573         1309200
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         8         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         1         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

SCT Commands not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (empty) ==
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (empty) ==
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (empty) ==
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (empty) ==
0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (empty) ==
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x000a  2            3  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk is in a very bad shape, so don't even keep it online for longer than
necessary to try and rescue the data.

The most problematic errors are (descriptions from Wikipedia [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)):

| Error | Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 187 | Reported Uncorrectable Errors | 2336 | The count of errors that could not be recovered using hardware ECC |
| 250 | Read Error Retry Rate | 190010 | Count of errors while reading from a disk |

The best tool for creating a clone of the disk is
[ddrescue](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ddrescue).
This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1587437/8672)
might help if it takes too long.